# Does it make a difference in how you initialize a string in modern C++?

Tags: c++

Is there a difference or is just a matter of preference? I'm a beginner to c++ and it bothers me that I am not confident that I'm choosing the right way to initialize a string value.

If I were to just choose one way which works for the vast majority of use cases, which would it be?

```
// Initializing from a literal.
std::string s1{"hello"};
std::string s2("there");
std::string s3 = {"what"};
std::string s4 = "is";

// Initializing from another string object.
std::string s5{s1};
std::string s6(s1);
std::string s7 = s1;
std::string s8 = {s1};
```

PS: Apologies if this question in it's entirety has been asked before, I couldn't find it anywhere and would appreciate it if someone could link to it here.

Comment: I recommend rewording your question to ask about the general technical differences between those different ways of initializing a string, as asking for "the right way" might be closed as off-topic (primarily opinion based).

Comment: I expect modern C++ compilers to generate identical code for all of the logically equivalent alternatives. So this is purely a matter of personal opinion and preferences.

Comment: @MaxVollmer - Good call - edited the question slightly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - Thanks, would you state it as a fact that all compilers would treat them as equivalent? Or are there certain situations where one is preferred over the other? It's a bit strange that c++ allows so many ways to initialize a string, there must be some reasoning behind it other than backwards compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For strings in particular, you will always be able to use all of the above, and it's really just a matter of personal preference.

I personally prefer

```
auto s1 = std::string(); //Initialize empty string
auto s2 = std::string("Hello, world"); // Initialize string containing "Hello, world"
auto s3 = s2; //Make a copy of s2
auto s4 = std::move(s3); //Move s3 into s4
```

And the reason I prefer that is because it works on all types. You can't forget to initialize something if you use auto:

```
int i; //Oops, forgot to initialize i, because i is a primitive
```

Versus:

```
auto i = 0; //i set to 0
auto i2 = size_t(0); //i2 is a size, and set to 0
auto i3; //Error: forgot to initialize
```

The important thing is to remain consistent throughout the codebase.